# issue with saving value as id on the dropdown angular

Tags: angular, angular7

i am having a dropdown which is used for populating country and state list when selecting a particular country state list will be populated . It is working perfectly. My issue is i want to save the id of country when submit. But now it is saving as object with full list id,name,created date,time etc.. my code is given below

```
<ng-autocomplete [data]="countryList" formControlName="country"
                             (selected)="changeState($event,countryList,'country')"

                            [searchKeyword]="keywordCountry" placeHolder="Enter country name"
                             [itemTemplate]="countryTemplate"
                             [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
            </ng-autocomplete>

            <ng-template #countryTemplate let-item value="id" >
              <a  [innerHTML]="item.name" ></a>
            </ng-template>


            <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
              <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
            </ng-template>


changeState(event,countryId) {
console.log('event');
console.log('countryId');
if (countryId && event) {
  let _this = this;
 _this.stateList = [];
  var getId = typeof event == 'object' ? event.id : event;
  var countryId = _.find(countryId, {id: parseInt(getId, 10)});
  console.log("countryId", countryId);
  this.selectedCountry = countryId.id;
  console.log('this.selectedCountry',this.selectedCountry);


  _this.CS.getStateList({ id: countryId.id }).subscribe(response => {
    console.log("response",response);
    if (response && response.status == "success" && response.result && response.result.length > 0) {
      _this.stateList = response.result[0].CS;
      console.log("_this.stateList",_this.stateList);
    } else {
    //  _this.stateList = [];
    }
```

Result

country:
createdAt: "2020-04-02T14:28:28.924Z"
id: 2
name: "Albania"
updatedAt: "2020-04-02T14:28:28.924Z"

expected result:

country:2

Answer (score 0):

I can see the issue in your code. You don't need to pass countryList and country in changeState method. Please replace this in your code:

In HTML Replace this

```
(selected)="changeState($event,countryList,'country')"
```

with

```
(selected)="changeState($event)"
```

and in your ts file

```
changeState(event,countryId) {
console.log('event');
console.log('countryId');
if (countryId && event) {
  let _this = this;
 _this.stateList = [];
  var getId = typeof event == 'object' ? event.id : event;
  var countryId = _.find(countryId, {id: parseInt(getId, 10)});
  console.log("countryId", countryId);
  this.selectedCountry = countryId.id;
  console.log('this.selectedCountry',this.selectedCountry);


  _this.CS.getStateList({ id: countryId.id }).subscribe(response => {
    console.log("response",response);
    if (response && response.status == "success" && response.result && response.result.length > 0) {
      _this.stateList = response.result[0].CS;
      console.log("_this.stateList",_this.stateList);
    } else {
    //  _this.stateList = [];
    }
```

with

```
changeState(event) {
   const countryId = event.id;
  _this.CS.getStateList({ id: countryId }).subscribe(response => {
    console.log("response",response);
    if (response && response.status == "success" && response.result && response.result.length > 0) {
      _this.stateList = response.result[0].CS;
      console.log("_this.stateList",_this.stateList);
    } else {
    //  _this.stateList = [];
    }
```

Comment: still issue ...it is not saving id..error object object